# Determine choices for questions - php regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a result from an array. I got this result by using this regex `preg_split('/(?=[a-z\d]+\.(?!\d))/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is foo?
    [1] => a. foo1
    [2] => b. foo2
    [3] => c. foo3
    [4] => d. foo4
    [5] => 2. What is foo 2.1? 
    [6] => a. foo3
    [7] => b. foo4
    [8] => c. foo1
    [9] => d. foo2
)
```

What I want to do with the choices is that they know which question they belong (i.e. index[1] to index[4] belongs to index[0])

Comment: You can loop through the array and check the first char: if it is a number there has to be a new question therefor the entries following on the current one are answers till you get a number again.

Comment: So inside the array I will have a preg_match or preg_match_all to capture if it is a number?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I managed to the questions to my db but I'm having trouble in inserting the choices because I'm confused what should I do with '$question'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and check the first char: if it is a number there has to be a new question therefor the entries following on the current one are answers till you get a number again.

Try it like this: https://eval.in/281411

```
$entries = array(
    0 => '1. What is foo?',
    1 => 'a. foo1',
    2 => 'b. foo2',
    3 => 'c. foo3',
    4 => 'd. foo4',
    5 => '2. What is foo 2.1?', 
    6 => 'a. foo3',
    7 => 'b. foo4',
    8 => 'c. foo1',
    9 => 'd. foo2'
);

$questions = array();
$currentQuestion = null;

foreach($entries as $entry) {
  if(is_numeric(substr($entry, 0, 1)) === true) {
      $currentQuestion = $entry;
      $questions[$entry] = array();
      continue;
  }

  $questions[$currentQuestion][] = $entry;
}

var_dump($questions);
```

Comment: I would add your code to your answer incase eval.in decided to purge, or eval.in dies.... or whatever.

Comment: This explanation is thorough, I appreciate your effort in helping me.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I managed to the questions to my db but I'm having trouble in inserting the choices because I'm confused what should I do with '$question' in order to get the choices...

Comment: @yowza I would [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and give a dump of your DB table and your PHP script to fetch it. I'll take a look at it once you do.

Answer (score 1):

#### array_chunk

You could use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) (assuming each Q&A has 1 question and 4 possible answers). Index `0` will always be the question, then you have the possible answers.

```
array_chunk($array, 5);
```

https://eval.in/281396

#### foreach()

You could use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) approach and check the element is a question by using [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos). This will group each question and answer in it's own array, inset `0` key will be the question. It's more flexible than the [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) method, as it allows for more than 4 answers.

```
foreach($array as $key => $qanda) {
   if( strpos($qanda, "?") ) {
      $final[$key] = array($qanda);
      $question = $key;
      continue;
   }

   $final[$question][] = $qanda; 
}
```

https://eval.in/281412

Comment: in some cases that there is more than 4 possible answers what should I do?
awesome website btw to test php codes!

Answer (score 1):

One more question is to tweak the regex and use `preg_match_all`:

```
$str = '1. What is Foo? a. foo1 b. foo2 c. foo3 d. foo4 e. foo5 2. What is foo 2.1? a. foo3 b. foo4 c. foo1 d. foo2';
preg_match_all('/(?:(\d+\..+?)|([a-z]+\..+?))(?=[a-z\d]+\.(?!\d)|\z)/', $str, $m);

# questions
print_r($m[1]);
Array
(
    [0] => 1. What is Foo?
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
    [5] =>
    [6] => 2. What is foo 2.1?
    [7] =>
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
    [10] =>
)

# multiple choices
print_r($m[2]);
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => a. foo1
    [2] => b. foo2
    [3] => c. foo3
    [4] => d. foo4
    [5] => e. foo5
    [6] =>
    [7] => a. foo3
    [8] => b. foo4
    [9] => c. foo1
    [10] => d. foo2
)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have endeavored sir!